# JQuery Mobile Panel No Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I copied the demos almost exactly, but my panel doesn't slide in...it just pops up as an overlay. I'm using JQM 1.4.1 and PhoneGap.

```
<div data-role="panel" id="nav-popup-menu" data-position="left" data-transition="slide" data-display="overlay" data-dismissible="true">
  <button class="search">Search</button>
</div>

.ui-panel {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
  width: 200px;
}

<a href="#nav-popup-menu" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" style="background-color: #f6f5f4; border-color: #f6f5f4; color: #f6f5f4; ">|</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: panels has no `data-transition`, only `data-display`, `push`, `overlay` and `reveal`. Btw, there's a bug on 1.4.1 on closing panel, use 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-role="panel" id="nav-popup-menu" data-position="left"  data-display="push">
  <button class="search">Search</button>
</div>

<a href="#nav-popup-menu" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" style="background-color: #f6f5f4; border-color: #f6f5f4; color: #f6f5f4; ">|</a>
```

Remove data-transition from the property . And set data-display push . [Here is Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQaYc/)

Are you looking for same ?